# Python problems with print

Tags: python

Today I've chosen to learn a new language, Python. I have some knowledge in C.
I started with Pythonista 3 on my iPad (was on the go), now I'm home, copied my code, and I have the following problem:

```
#!/use/bin/python

startNumber = 3 #1000329977989
endNumber = startNumber + 100 #int(input('Enter the ending number:'))
numberToTest = startNumber

string = '1 is prime!'
print(string)
string = '2 is prime!'
print(string)
string = '3 is prime!'
print(string)

while numberToTest < endNumber -1:
    for numberToTest in range(startNumber, endNumber):
        testerRangeEnd = int(numberToTest**(1/2))
        for tester in range(2, testerRangeEnd):
            if numberToTest % tester == 0:
                string = str(numberToTest) + ' is not prime!'
                print(string)
                numberToTest += 1
                break
            if tester == testerRangeEnd - 1:
                string = str(numberToTest) + ' is prime!'
                print(string)

print("Done!")
```

Outputs:

```
1 is prime!
2 is prime!
3 is prime!
Done!
```

Why do the prints in the while loop not print? I don't get it at all... Miss my parenthesis, semicolons and brackets... :(

Cheers
/Leic

Comment: you do not need the `for` loop inside the `while` or to put it another way, you just need one of them, not both.

Comment: Try pasting your code into https://pythontutor.com to visualise its execution.

Comment: You're right, but that doesn't change the fact that it isn't printing...

Comment: By the way, 1 is not a prime.

Comment: Tried pythontutor as suggested, prints everything as should... Could it be a problem with different versions of python? Or am I trying to print too much?

Comment: If you're using Python 2, then change `(1/2)` to `0.5`, since `1/2` is zero in Python 2.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @khelwool (1/2) -> (0.5) did it! Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Consider switching now to Python 3 before you get too far learning Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this line:

```
testerRangeEnd = int(numberToTest**(1/2))
```

1/2 gives 0 because it's integer division. So `for tester in range(2, testerRangeEnd):` equals to `iteration for tester in []:` and itearation won't start.

You should convert this numbers to float:  `1.0/2 = 0.5`